# Disable parallel DML on Autonomous Database (ADB)?

Tags: parallel-processing, dml, oracle-autonomous-db

Users have noticed an "ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object" after modifying it in parallel error in their ADB instance

The low, medium and high services seem to have parallel DML enabled by default.

Do we have any recommendations to deal with parallel DML execution on ADB Shared?

Answer (score 1):

On ADB-Shared, Parallel DML is enabled by default. If your application does not support P-DML, a workaround would be to disable P-DML at the session level as below. You may also trigger this via a LOGON trigger.

> ALTER SESSION DISABLE PARALLEL DML;

Parallel DML brings you performance benefits with the limitation of touch-once. In general, the best practice is to apply parallel DML where it brings benefits and to fall back to serial DML when truly required.